# Is there a way to display the execution time of a program using a Xcode?

Tags: xcode

A few IDEs like CodeBlocks display the execution time of the program once it terminates. Is there a way to do the same the in Xcode as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.You have to use the build-in Instruments.There,you will find lot's of infos for your app and it is highly recommended to get used to it.

To launch it ,press

> ⌘I

Instruments will appear,and you can chose Time Profiler.

Hope this helps :)